# IndexError: index 666 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 501

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

```
import math
import numpy as np

def ExplicitMethod(S0, K, r, q, T, Sigma, M, N, Option):

    M = int(M)
    N = int(N)
    dt = T / N
    K = float(K)
    Smax = 2 * K
    dS = Smax / N

    FGrid = np.zeros(shape=(N+1, M+1))

    if Option == 'Call':
        FGrid[-1, :] = np.maximum(np.arange(0, M+1) * dS - K, 0)  
    elif Option == 'Put':
        FGrid[-1, :] = np.maximum(K - np.arange(0, M+1) * dS, 0)

    A = np.zeros(shape=(M+1, M+1))
    A[0,0] = 1
    A[-1,-1] = 1
    for j in range(1, M-1):
        A[j, (j-1,j, j+1)] = \
        [0.5 * dt * (Sigma ** 2 * j ** 2 - (r - q) * j  ), \
         1 - dt * (Sigma ** 2 * j ** 2 + r), \
         0.5 * dt * (Sigma **2 * j ** 2 + (r - q) * j)]


    for i in range(N):
        Fhat = FGrid [i, ]
        FGrid[i, :] = np.dot(A , Fhat)
        Fhat[0] = 0
        Fhat[-1] = Smax - K * math.exp(-r * (N - i) * dt)

    k = math.floor(S0 / dS)

    V = FGrid[0, k] + (FGrid[0, k] - FGrid[0, k]) / dS * [(S0 - k * dS)]

    print (V)

ExplicitMethod (50, 30, 0.1, 0.05, 2, 0.3, 400, 800, Option = 'Call')
```

And I got this error:

> IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        37     print (V)
>        38 
>   ---> 39 ExplicitMethod (50, 30, 0.1, 0.05, 2, 0.3, 400, 800, Option = 'Call')
>
> in ExplicitMethod(S0, K, r, q, T,
>   Sigma, M, N, Option)
>        33     k = math.floor(S0 / dS)
>        34 
>   ---> 35     V = FGrid[0, k] + (FGrid[0, k] - FGrid[0, k]) / dS * [(S0 - k * dS)]
>        36 
>        37     print (V)
>
> IndexError: index 666 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 401

And FYI I'm coding Option Pricing Explicit Method:

[image]

Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have initialized `FGrid` to be (801,401).  The tells us that, for some reason, `k=666`

```
k = math.floor(S0 / dS)
V = FGrid[0, k] + (FGrid[0, k] - FGrid[0, k]) / dS * [(S0 - k * dS)]
```

You need to refine how `k` is set.  Maybe the math is wrong.  At the very least you need to ensure that it does not get above 400.

```
In [200]: S0=50; K=30; N=800
In [201]: dS = 2*K/N
In [202]: dS
Out[202]: 0.075
In [203]: S0/dS
Out[203]: 666.6666666666667
```

There's your `666`.